# Python clear screen problem cross-platform

Tags: python

I am a python beginner, and I am working on an interactive shell/terminal.
I want to clear screen interactively with input.
Would someone help me please, figure out a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do it with system Lib.
If you’re using linux or mac :

```
system('clear')
```

Windows :

```
system('cls')
```

This a general function :

```
from os import system, name 

def clear(): 

    # for windows 
    if name == 'nt': 
        _ = system('cls') 

    # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix') 
    else: 
        _ = system('clear')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It's working

Comment: well you should make a little web search to find how to fix your problems